# Q-Q plot with data frames in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics

I need some help.
I want to draw a Q-Q plot for each column of a dataframe in python. Here is the sample dataframe from my database:

```
my_dict = {'age':[16,33,54,37,66,17,5,14,22,42],
           'avg_glucose_level':[88.85,121.04,129.16,87.16,103.01,68.66,84.93,111.27,79.81,55.22]}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/installing/index.html) and [statesmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/install.html) library (go to the links if you need to install them) as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

my_dict = {'age':[16,33,54,37,66,17,5,14,22,42],
           'avg_glucose_level':[88.85,121.04,129.16,87.16,103.01,68.66,84.93,111.27,79.81,55.22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

a = np.random.normal(5, 5, 250)
sm.qqplot(df['age'])
sm.qqplot(df['avg_glucose_level'])
plt.show()
```